# how to access the data stored in android emulator.?

Tags: android

For my application I have access the data stored in emulator i.e. contacts, messages, images etc. I have to access this data in binary format and store it in to the array. Is there any method to access the emulators data in the above format? Which API's can I use to access this data. I don't have to use content provider.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read up on Android's Data Storage page? [Data Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

I think if you want to access images you want to read up on the External Storage chapter